# In java, how can i declare a variable inside an if lambda condition?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In my code, i have a predicate method that returns `i` if certain conditions are met, and i need to declare a variable inside it, but the method is written in lambda, and i don't know how to do this. 
Here's my code:

```
public static Predicate<MFDWHDealExt> isAccepted() {
        MyCalendar startDate = new MyCalendar();

        return (i -> 
                i.getCompany().equals("ACCEPTED")
                && i.getDealType() == MFDealTypeEnum.AcceptedDeal              
                && i.getSettlementDate().beforeOrEqual(startDate.findDay(i.getDealDate(), 2, true))
                );
    }
```

i need to declare `startDate` (a custom date `MyDate`) with the value of `i.getSettlementDate`, otherwise the method `findDay`(that returns working days), because right now is `null`.

Comment: Declaring a variable you don't use does nothing. If i.getSettlementDate does the job, you can just call that.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
    return (i -> { 
            return i.getCompany().equals("ACCEPTED")
              && i.getDealType() == MFDealTypeEnum.AcceptedDeal              
              && i.getSettlementDate().beforeOrEqual(startDate.findDay(i.getDealDate(), 2, true))
            });
```

When **not** using the **one line** syntax of lambdas, like `x-> 2*x`, you need block braces. And you can't use that one-line syntax when you intend to declare a local variable.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) for the official documentation!

In other words: when you want to write several statements, like actually defining a local variable, then you need these braces!

Finally: be careful what you do here. (imho) Lambda expressions should be really short and concise. When they become "more complicated" (like: they need local variables), then I suggest to not use a lambda, but to declare a real method and call that.

Answer (score 4):

Just use code block in lambda and declare your variable inside.

```
public static Predicate<MFDWHDealExt> isAccepted() {
    MyCalendar startDate = new MyCalendar();

    return (i -> {
            MyDate startDate = i.getSettlementDate();
            boolean result = i.getCompany().equals("ACCEPTED")
            && i.getDealType() == MFDealTypeEnum.AcceptedDeal              
            && startDate.beforeOrEqual(startDate.findDay(i.getDealDate(), 2, true));
            return result;
            });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, i get a compile error "this is not a statement" on the i.getCompany(). EDIT : nevermind, i forgot the second return. It works now, thank you!

Comment: If you use the version with braces you need to add the return keyword

Answer (score 3):

A lambda expression is a shortcut for an anonymous class implementing an interface with a single method.

You can define anythink you like inside that unique method.

The lambda expression:

```
 (a, b) -> {
    // Your code here      
 }
```

is equivalent to:

```
 new MyInterface() {
    public ReturnType uniqueMethod(AType a, BType b) {
        // Exactly the same code here
    }
 }
```

Depeding on the kind of anonymous class derived from the interface that you need to write the `ReturnType` can be also `void` and the number of parameters can be 0, or any number of parameters (in this case two parameters of type `AType` and `BType`)

The following form of lambda expression:

```
(a, b) -> something
```

is another shortcut and is equivalent to:

```
   new MyInterface() {
       public ReturnType uniqueMethod(AType a, BType b) {
           // Same as before but with the additional keyword return
           return something;
       }
    }
```

In your case you have to apply the first form of lambda expression with the block `{ }` and you can define any kind and number of variables inside the brackets

Answer (score 1):

You need expand it to code block;

```
    return (i -> { 
            int myVar;
            return i.getCompany().equals("ACCEPTED")
               && i.getDealType() == MFDealTypeEnum.AcceptedDeal              
               && i.getSettlementDate().beforeOrEqual(startDate.findDay(i.getDealDate(), 2, true));
            });
```